# How Do I get URN with OSS, Autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk, forge, urn

I have gone through developer.autodesk.com to know more about Forge Platform and I am still looking for the way with which I can get URN of my obj file.

I just need a sample code to move ahead. :)

Comment: the object files can be on buckets or under your A360 account, in either case, you need Data Management API. Can you add more details on your question?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs

```
here : learn.forge.viewmodels/www/js/ForgeViewer.js
```

on this file u can see the usage of URN and u can watch it easily just by monitor it with console.log or other methods...